# Give root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):

Tags: boot, grub2, password, recovery-mode, password-recovery

I just upgraded Ubuntu today and when it's restarted it's showing subject message. The main problem is I forgot my root password. Now it's repeatedly saying: `Give root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):`

I tried to start in recovery mode but:

1. Recovery mode is displayed as shown below and the arrow keys are not working to select the root option.

[image: ScreenShot]

2. After some seconds the same message appears in Recovery mode as follows:

[image: ScreenShot]

I am not able to login.

Comment: *"arrow keys are not working"* and *"input overrun at /dev/tty1"* suggests a physical keyboard issue - see for example [Ubuntu xenial server on virtualbox recovery mode times out and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/a/881916/178692)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I changed 3 physical keyboards but still same problem. Perhaps this is not the main issue in my case as all keyboards that I changed are working well in linuc as well as in windows environment